# :active pseudo class stuck on firefox android (because of google maps?)

Tags: android, html, css, google-maps, firefox

I'm building a simple website and want to do something apparently even simpler: trigger a feedback animation when a user clicks on a button.

In order to do that, I use the `:active` pseudo class:

```
button {
  background-color: inherit;
  transition: all 1s;
}
button:active {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  transition: all 0s;
}
```

It works well, when the button is clicked, it darkens instantly then slowly brightens back to the original color.

Except on firefox on android, where the button stays dark. If I touch elsewhere, the buttons brightens back.
It seem like the `:active` class is stuck on the button. It doesn't happen on desktop, and it doesn't happen on chrome on android, but it does happen in firefox and firefox nightly on android.

Even weirder, it only happens on my website, it doesn't happen on MDN's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active
And when I copy paste the example from there on my website, it happens.

So I suspected there was something funny with my website, or some missing magic setting. I'm using angular 16 to build it. I tried removing everything I could think of, until I removed the googlemaps import I have in `<head>`, and then the bug disappears

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey"></script>
```

But the thing is, I need gmaps, so I have to import it.

If any of you has any idea how to solve that, I'd be most thankful.

Comment: If the script tag is causing the issue, and since you are using Angular, have you tried just importing the Google Maps Component instead of explicitly importing it in the head? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps

Comment: @Yrll I tried that too (in version 16 though https://github.com/angular/components/blob/16.2.x/src/google-maps/README.md ) but it does the same. The moment I call the API with `httpClient.jsonp(...` it breaks. I even used a setTimeout to delay the call. Before, it works, after, it breaks. It's quite baffling.

Comment: You might want to try filing an issue in the github repo or file a bug in the public issue tracker. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a look, though I don't have much hope. In the meantime, I ended up using an embedded map (through an iframe), it solves the problem.